# How to set different thumbnail sizes per custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have many custom post types like podcast,news etc. All I want to create different size of thumbnails for each post type. Like for news I want thumbnails of 200*100 and 300*100, for podcast 200*100 and 150*100 means certain sizes for certain post types not for others (To avoid waste of space).

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Thumbnail sizes are defined for whole page. What you can do is to use a library like [timthumb.php](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) and your specific post type images through that when generating image outputs.

Answer (score -1):

`add_image_size()` can help you,
In your theme functions file
set image sizes for post
for example

```
add_image_size('new-size',200,100, true);
```

now you can use `the_post_thumbnail()` as usual but include the new image size to display that instead of the thumbnail default for different post type:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'new-size' );
```

Comment: You did not get my question correctly.I want to create thumbnails of new size only for specified post type not for all available post types